# Can't stop background service android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service

I'm running the following background service:

```
public class TranslationService  extends IntentService implements ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener {

    private Language mFrom;
    private Language mTo;
    private String mTranslation;
    private ClipboardManager mClipboardManager;

    public TranslationService() {
        super("hello");
    }

    public TranslationService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mFrom = (Language) intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.FROM_STRING);
        mTo = (Language) intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.TO_STRING);
        mClipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        mClipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(this);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {

        ClipData clip = mClipboardManager.getPrimaryClip();
        String copiedText = clip.getItemAt(0).getText().toString();
        connectToTranslationApi(copiedText);

        //TODO solve concurrency problems if app works inconsistently.
        try {
           Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), mTranslation, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    }

    private void connectToTranslationApi(String copiedPhrase) {

        String apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        String fromInitials = mFrom.initials;
        String toInitials = mTo.initials;
        String yandexUrl = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key="+
                apiKey + "&lang=" +
                fromInitials + "-" + toInitials +
                "&text="+ copiedPhrase;

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(yandexUrl).build();
        Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                //TODO handle failure
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String jsonData = response.body().string();
                    try {mTranslation = getTextTranslation(jsonData);}
                    catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private String getTextTranslation(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String translation = data.getString("text");
       translation = translation.replace("]", "")
                    .replace("[", "")
                    .replace("\"", "");
        return translation;
    }

}
```

The service runs in the background and translates text that I copy to the clipboard (even when I use other apps. The service will only stop if I remove the app that launched it from RAM) and this is all fine.

However, when I come back to the app's main activity and press "Stop Service" It will not stop. Here is the code that starts (and supposed to stop) the service

```
         if(mIsServiceRunning == false) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TranslationService.class);
            i.putExtra(FROM_STRING, mLanguageFrom);
            i.putExtra(TO_STRING, mLanguageTo);
            startService(i);
            mIsServiceRunning = true;
            startButton.setText("Stop Service");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TranslationService.class);
            stopService(i);
            mIsServiceRunning = false;
            startButton.setText("Start Service");
        }
```

Any Ideas how to stop it?

Comment: how do you know it's not stopping?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirly sure exactly how you are sure that your service is still running.
but I would recommend not to base it on that mIsServiceRunning boolean.

you can use this method to make sure it's running or not :

```
public static boolean isServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
  ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
    if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

this method will return a boolean that tells you if the service runs in the background or not, 
you can use it like this for example :

```
if (isServiceRunning(TranslationService.class)) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Service is Running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Service is NOT Running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Maybe I'm missing it too, but I don't see any mistake in your code.

```
context.stopService(new Intent(context, TranslationService.class));
```

should stop your service.

Hope that helps you, if not, try and provide with some more information after you tried that.

Comment: Well, a translation still pops every time I copy to clipboard, and the method to do so is in the service's class, so I can't see how it is possible that it is NOT still running. By the way, at the code you suggested, at WorkoutApplication.getInstance() what should I replace WorkoutApplication with?

Comment: aw sorry, i'll edit that, WorkoutApplication.getInstance() is the context.

Answer (score 0):

There is a memory leak because you left clipboard method without destroying it.
you need to make listener for clear  clipboard object from the ram after particular activity destroyed.Despite Services stopped but this clipboard method running in memory.You need to stop by this code

> clipboardManager.removePrimaryClipChangedListener(listener);

on whatever onDestroy(),onPause() method.

Try to understand this below code

```
public class MySecretService extends Service {

ClipboardManager clipboardManager;
ClipData clipData;
ClipData.Item item;
String text;
//declare Listener 
ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener listener;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service is Started !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service is Created !!! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //fire intent
    intent = new Intent(MySecretService.this, DictionaryActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    final Intent finalIntent = intent;

    //asign listener to onPrimaryClipChangedListner 
    clipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(listener = new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
            clipData = clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip();
            item = clipData.getItemAt(0);
            try {
                text = item.getText().toString();

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MySecretService.this, "exception " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Toast.makeText(MySecretService.this, "Text is Copiyed " + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //startActivity when copy triggered on text
            startActivity(finalIntent);
        }

    });


    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // DictionaryActivity.finishAll();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service is Destroyed !!! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //free from memroy
    clipboardManager.removePrimaryClipChangedListener(listener);

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same thing I notice that as long the app is cached in the memory the service will run. I will try to add if else statement in the service to check the preference/setting so that even if the service running or cached it will check the shared preference and decide to either continue or stop. (it is bad to keep it checking if the it off but i can't figure something else

Answer (score 0):

you need to call stopservice(intent) method from where you want to stop it and override  onDestroy() in service class,now stopservice() will call destroy method of service class now you can place your code to disconnect ongoing process in onDestroy().

i got my result after so much effort !Hope you go your answer!